# PDE with implicitly defined dependent variable

Tags: differential-equations

I have a differential equation containing an implicitly defined function.

```
aa[x_, y_] := we[x] y^2 + y^3

D[aa[x, y], {x, y}] - y^4*D[aa[x, y], {x, 2}] - 1/y*D[aa[x, y], x] == 0
```

How can I solve for `we[x]` as function of `x`when `y = 3` and know `aa[x_, y_] = 0` when `y = 0`

Answer (score 4):

We can solve for the general soln of `we`

```
aa[x_, y_] := we[x] y^2 + y^3

pde = D[aa[x, y], {x, y}] - y^4*D[aa[x, y], {x, 2}] - 1/y*D[aa[x, y], x] == 0
```

The condition on `aa` for `y==0` is satisfied by the definition of `aa`.

```
pde /. y -> 3
(* 9 D[we[x],{x,3}]-729 D[we[x],{x,2}]-3 D[we[x],x]==0 *)

DSolve[%, we[x], x] // Flatten
(* {we[x]->1/2 (-243-Sqrt[59061]) C[1] E^(-((2 x)/(243+Sqrt[59061])))+(6 C[2] E^(1/6 (243+Sqrt[59061]) x))/(243+Sqrt[59061])+C[3]} *)
```

But you need more conditions on `we` to find the three constants, before you can plot.

Comment: if I have  `aa[x,y]=3` when y=2

Comment: If `aa[x,2]==3` you can solve for `we[x] = -5/4`, a const.  Does not make much of a plot.